# Disable Panning in ArcGIS API for Silverlight map?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

Is there a way to disable panning when using the ArcGIS Silverlight API?

Other than enabling a Draw object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myMap.IsEnabled = true;
```

According to [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2455&t=298676) ESRI forum thread.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I have to think that that should be _false_, not true. Unless they misnamed the property.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set

```
Map.IsHitTestVisible = false
```

This disables mouse events on the map.  Can be used for any UIElement in Silverlight.